# issue on saving category image in backend

Tags: magento2, category-image

After saving category image in backend, on inspect that element src comes with rootfolder/pathof the image .so that category image is not displayed on the front end .

Comment: Image add after run the reindex command??

Comment: yes but it is not worked

Answer (score 0):

I guess your Magento version is 2.3.3 within which on category save an image is not updated or set to blank after first save. This issue is fixed in latest Magento version 2.3.4.

Comment: Im using magento 2.3.4

Comment: Is the uploaded image present on the path that you have seen after inspecting? Do verify max_upload_size value configured for your server in phpinfo().